# Nested expandable list view edit text collapses list view

Tags: android, xml, expandablelistview

Hi all I have constructed this nested expandable list and everything is working correctly except when the edit text is focused the whole list gets collapsed. Code for both providers and xml views. What am i missing here ?

outer list

```
public class DashboardDrawerExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context mAdapterContext;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    private ExpandableListView mParent;

    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;


    public DashboardDrawerExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, ExpandableListView parent) {
        this.mAdapterContext = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this.mParent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mAdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_drawer_inner_expandable_list_header, null);
        }

        prepareInnerListData();

        ExpandableListView innerExpandableList =(ExpandableListView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inner_expandable_list);
        DashboardDrawerExpandableInnerListAdapter drawerexpandableadapter = new DashboardDrawerExpandableInnerListAdapter(mAdapterContext, listDataHeader, listDataChild,innerExpandableList);
        innerExpandableList.setAdapter(drawerexpandableadapter);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mAdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.dashboard_drawer_expandable_list_header_item, null); // main greyed header
            TextView groupHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.groupHeaderText);
            groupHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            groupHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    private void prepareInnerListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        // Adding child data
        listDataHeader.add("Date Range");
        listDataHeader.add("Location(s)");

        // Adding child data
        List<String> filteritems = new ArrayList<String>();
        filteritems.add(" ");

        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0), filteritems);
        listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), filteritems);
    }
}
```

inner list

```
public class DashboardDrawerExpandableInnerListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    Context mAdapterContext;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;
    private ExpandableListView mParent;

    public DashboardDrawerExpandableInnerListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData, ExpandableListView parent) {
        this.mAdapterContext = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
        this.mParent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mAdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            switch (groupPosition){
                case 0:
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_item_date_range, null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_item_locations, null);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mAdapterContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            switch (groupPosition){
                case 0:
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_header_date_range, null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_header_location, null);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        TextView groupHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inner_group_header_text);
        groupHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        groupHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
```

outer list xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#616161"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/groupHeaderText"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

inner list xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:isScrollContainer="false"
        android:id="@+id/inner_expandable_list" />

</LinearLayout>
```